# java package returning value to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, import, return, package

I have a user defined package named apt1.java, i import it in a servlet named aptservlet1.java. It run correctly but return only false value immaterial of correct argument. If i am using this package by simple java program(that have output in command prompt) than it gives correct answer.

please answer this question.. 
fllowing are my programs..

aptservlet1.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class aptservlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        boolean correct;
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        String user, pass;
        user = req.getParameter("user");
        pass = req.getParameter("pass");
        apt1 o1 = new apt1();
        correct = o1.confirmadmin(user, pass);
        out.println("value of correct=" + correct);
        ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
        if (correct) {
            out.println("correct");

        }
        if (correct) {
            out.println("incorret");
        }
    }
}
```

apt1.java:

```
public class apt1 {
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + "aptitude";

public apt1() {
    try {
        Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
    }
}

public boolean confirmadmin(String user, String pass) {
    boolean c = false;
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + "aptitude";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s
                .executeQuery("select a_pass from admin_database where          a_user='"
                        + user + "'");
        rs.next();
        String s1 = rs.getString(1);
        int k = s1.compareTo(pass);
        if (k == 0) {
            c = true;
        } else {
            c = false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

Comment: You could think about replacing `int k=s1.compareTo(pass);` and the following if/else-block by `return s1.equals(pass);`.

Comment: You're doing this wrong anyway. You should search for rows matching that user *and password,* and just test that there was one. Let the database do the comparing. Also the password should be hashed, which again the database can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo here:

```
if(correct){
    out.println("correct");

}
if(correct) {
    out.println("incorret");}
}
```

This will print out both correct and incorret when correct is true.

Try:

```
if(correct){
    out.println("correct");

}
if(!correct) {
    out.println("incorret");}
}
```

Comment: So, you mean `else`? And you have an additional curly bracket (`}`) after the "incorrect" output. That should be removed.

Comment: sir, actually problem is not due to value of 'correct'.i am facing problem in accessing mysql database by servlet. but i am able to access database by simple java program(not servlet). when i access database by server it shows "no suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost